# Not showing FCM notification

Tags: php, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send a notifiction to my device when my phone is offline(Not connected to internet).After 5 or 6 minutes I connected the phone to internet but I didn't got the notification i sent earlier. How can i get the notitfication after connect to internet.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    Integer notify_no = 0;

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
           /* Integer badge = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("badge"));
            Log.d("notificationNUmber",":"+badge);
            setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badge);*/
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
         notify_no = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("msgcnt"));

        if (notify_no < 1) {
            notify_no = notify_no + 1;
        } else {
            notify_no = 0;
        }





        //EventBus.getDefault().post(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());



        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }




public void sendNotification(String messageBody)
 {

     Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("messages","messages");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("fcm_notification", "Y");
       // startActivity(intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("content://settings/system/notification_sound"))
                .setVibrate(new long []{100,2000,500,2000})
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (NOTIFICATION_ID > 1073741824) {
            NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
        }
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notificationBuilder.build());


        // ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(badgeCount);
    }
}
```

How to get the notification after connect to internet?

I send using PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: how you send notification? server side or firebase console?

Comment: It will delivered as soon as possible

Comment: @Divyesh I send using php

Comment: then remove time_to_live parameter if you used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in the manual:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

> FCM usually delivers messages immediately after they are sent. However, this might not always be possible. For example, if the platform is Android, the device could be turned off, offline, or otherwise unavailable. FCM might intentionally delay messages to prevent an app from consuming excessive resources and negatively affecting battery life.

and this:

> You can use the time_to_live parameter, supported in both HTTP and XMPP requests, to specify the maximum lifespan of a message. The value of this parameter must be a duration from 0 to 2,419,200 seconds, and it corresponds to the maximum period of time for which FCM stores and attempts to deliver the message. Requests that don't contain this field default to the maximum period of four weeks.

Comment: i changed time to live 2419200...Now its working Thanks @Vyacheslav